# Transmission capacity in "duobinary coding"

Tags: digital-communications, channelcoding

In "duo-binary signalling" how exactly is the transmission capacity increased?

Because , when we encode the binary bits, the bit duration remains the same, but the amplitude will change. Then how can the transmission capacity be better?

Comment: You say duobinary modulation doubled the capacity. Compared to what modulation scheme? Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: correlative coding is generally used to increase the bit rate, given the same bandwidth.I am not comparing it with any specific modulation scheme.but not understanding how capacity  will be increased.

Comment: _Capacity_ has a particular meaning in communications circles which is different from what is being considered here. What is happening is that the use of duobinary signaling allows for an increase in the transmission _rate_ (# of bits per second) or _spectral efficiency_  (bits per second per Hertz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transmit a symbol sequence $A_k$ using baseband pulse amplitude modulation (PAM), the transmitted signal is

$$s(t)=\sum_kA_kp(t-kT)$$

where $p(t)$ is the transmit pulse, and $T$ is the symbol interval. If you want to avoid intersymbol interference (ISI), the pulse function $p(t)$ must satisfy the Nyquist criterion, which says that its value must be zero at multiples of the symbol interval:

$$p(0)=1,\quad p(kT)=0,\quad k\neq 0\tag{1}$$

The minimum bandwidth required to satisfy (1) is $1/2T$, but the corresponding pulse $p(t)$ is an ideal low-pass filter, i.e. a sinc function, which is of course impractical. So in practice, Nyquist pulses with a higher bandwidth (excess bandwidth) are used. This means that for a given bandwidth, the possible symbol rate is reduced as compared to the theoretically maximum possible value.

With duobinary signalling practical systems can be built with *zero excess bandwidth*, because the data symbols are filtered such that a spectral zero is introduced at half the baud rate. Note that this is a very simple filter unlike the ideal low-pass filter required for the minimum bandwidth Nyquist pulse. The price paid is the deliberate introduction of ISI and the introduction of a ternary (instead of binary) signal, which requires a higher SNR to achieve a given error probability.

Comment: I think the _data_ are still binary but at the receiver, instead of needing to discriminate between two levels (say, $+A$ and $-A$), it is necessary to discriminate between _three_ levels ( $+B$ , $0$, and $-B$) to make a decision as to whether a $0$ or a $1$ was transmitted, and so, for a given noise level, $B$ must be larger than $A$ to achieve the same error probability.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Of course you're right, I shouldn't have referred to ternary *data*, but to a ternary signal (at the output of the filter). Edited.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. But i didnt get 2 points,1]what is the meaning of "for a given bandwidth, the possible symbol rate is reduced as compared to the theoretically maximum possible value." 2]"the data symbols are filtered such that a spectral zero is introduced at half the baud rate"

Comment: @spectre: 1) If you use excess bandwidth in order to be able to implement a Nyquist pulse, you use more bandwidth than theoretically necessary, i.e. for a given bandwidth you need to lower the data rate as compared to the theoretical maximum value. 2) The frequency response of the filter becomes zero at the frequency $1/2T$, where $T$ is the symbol period.

Comment: as far as i know,  bandwidth=(Rb)(1+a)/2, where, a=roll off factor,Rb=rate of transmission. So , for a given Bandwidth , data rate Rb is fixed right?@MattL.

Comment: @spectre: The maximum bandwidth ($a=0$) is fixed, but apart from that it depends on the roll off factor, i.e. on the excess bandwidth used for the pulse, that's what I meant. For a fixed bandwidth you obviously get different rates for $a=0$ and e.g. $a=1$.

Comment: But i didnt get how capacity can be increased in duo-binary coding.especially in second paragraph,explaination is not clear to me.can you please elaborate it?.Thanks in advance@MattL.

Comment: @spectre: OK, so for a practical Nyquist pulse you need a roll off factor $a>0$, so for a given bandwidth $B$ the data rate is $R=\frac{2B}{1+a}<2B$ (for $a>0$), whereas for duobinary signalling you get $R=2B$ because you can have zero roll off factor (or zero excess bandwidth), so the data rate is larger.

Comment: @Matt ,  i got the point that, if roll off factor is zero,data rate will be 2R for  given bandwidth.But a=0 is  impractical right?I didnt get how data rate R=2B in duobinary scheme?

Comment: @spectre: Because with duobinary signalling you have zero excess bandwidth. The filter response has the shape of a cosine with a gradual decay down to zero at half the data rate. So it's not discontinuous as the ideal lowpass filter, which can't be implemented. The price you pay for this is the introduction of ISI.

Comment: In ISI, if the binary pulse is represented by modified rised cosine, then we can avoid ISI.So,my Question is ,how having filter response in the shape of cosine with gradual delay will solve the problem?We need to determine the characteristic of output signal of the above filter to talk about Bandwidth and data rate of the signal, right?

Comment: @MattL., I understood what you are saying. But here,condition for ISI is violated right?[summation of {P{t-nRb}} as 'n' is varied, gives constant]